# node js how pass data to static html as a response to ajax call

Tags: node.js

. First of all i am newbie in node. I have read almost all similar posts but cannot figure out what is the best for my case. I make an ajax post request from a static html file sending a room name to join with. On server side i search my mongodb if there is a room with this particular name. If not, i want to return to the previous page sending also a message like "there isn't a room with this name". If i try res.send or res.json it redirects me to an empty page showing the message above. I do not prefer also making a url query. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks

```
$('#btn2').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/joinRoom',
                data: $('#roomJoin').val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }

            });
        })
```

app.js

```
app.post('/joinRoom', checkAuthentication,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    User.findOne({ createRoom:req.body.roomJoin }, function(err,obj){
        if(err){
            console.log(err.code);
        }
        else if(!obj) {           
            res.redirect('index_connected.html');

        } else if(obj){
            res.redirect('board.html');
        }
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending the message in the `url` query would be the easiest way to achieve this. If you don't want them you can try the below alternative.

Send a cookie from your server and on page load, check if you have the cookie. If you have it, show a message and delete the cookie. If not skip it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Aren't there security issues sending info through queries;

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
app.post('/joinRoom', checkAuthentication,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    User.findOne({ createRoom:req.body.roomJoin }, function(err,obj){
        if(err){
            console.log(err.code);
        }
        else if(!obj) {           
            res.redirect("index_connected.html/?message=there isn't a room with this name");

        } else if(obj){
            res.redirect('board.html');
        }
    });

})
```

Comment: Thanks but as i have written i do not prefer queries